# JQuery Mobile - Fill content div with map, no scroll

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I tried tons of solutions, but none of them worked.

I have a layout with fixed header and footer (real fixed not disappearing), and I like to obtain the filling of the `<div data-role="content">` with the map. I'm also looking to disable both vertical and horizontal scroll in this content div.

Solutions NOT working:
[Google Map extends off edge of page when embedded inside jQuery Mobile "page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912623/google-map-extends-off-edge-of-page-when-embedded-inside-jquery-mobile-page?rq=1) 
[google maps in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574097/google-maps-in-jquery-mobile?rq=1) 
[How to create div with 100% height with jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541780/how-to-create-div-with-100-height-with-jquery-mobile?rq=1) 
[JQuery-Mobile content area 100% height between head and foot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445977/jquery-mobile-content-area-100-height-between-head-and-foot) 
[Maximise div[data-role=content] in Jquery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161634/maximise-divdata-role-content-in-jquery-mobile?rq=1) 
[How can I display a full screen google map with jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406252/how-can-i-display-a-full-screen-google-map-with-jquery-mobile?rq=1)

Comment: Please post example or your code on http://jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than a year later, but if someone still want to solve this, here is how:

*tested with jquery mobile 1.3.1 and Google Maps API v3*

In HTML, use this for content:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</div>
```

**TIP:** Do not use `data-fullscreen` on any div of the page.

Than, in your CSS, use this:

```
#mapDiv {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 58px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

Remember to create your map inside your mapDiv, so your JS would be like:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), mapOptions);
```

And that's it! It's going to work even when you rotate a device showing it.

**TIP:** You must use `data-position="fixed"` and `data-tap-toggle="false"` in your header and footer.